# Insert auto incrementing variable names into database

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code that replaces {input:text} with an actual input field:

```
while (strpos($setCode, '{input:text}') !== false)
{
    $setCode = preg_replace('/{input:text}/', '<input class="bookTextInput" type="text" name="ANT'. $i++ . '" />', $setCode, 1);
}
```

What I want is to insert the values of all generated input fields into SQL:

```
$AntCount   = substr_count($string, '{input:text}');

for( $i= 1 ; $i <= $AntCount ; $i++ )   {

    $query  =   "INSERT INTO TableName (Answer) VALUES ('" . $ANT.$i . "')";
    mysqli_query($link, $query);
}
```

With this code only numbers are being inserted into the database ($i). The **$ANT** is being cancelled. I would like to insert the values of ANT1, ANT2 etc.

It seems that $ANT.$i doesnt work, is there a way to insert the automatically generated input field values in a way like this?

Comment: Does $ANT have a value here? And is `Answer` a varchar-column? If I understand you correctly, you can use `... values('ANT".$i."')";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANT is form field so is in POST, right?

So not: `$ANT.$i`

But: `$_POST['ANT'.$i]`

Comment: Thx! Works perfect like this:)

Answer (score 0):

$(ANT.$i)

hopefully it will work

Comment: Unfortunately doesnt work. $(ANT.$i) is not accepted. ($ANT.$i) gives the same result.